# trying to use preg_match_all to get table contents from page

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have an html page and I want to get the contents in a table.
the table starts with grid tag and ends with grid tag,

My function is this:

```
preg_match_all("/<grid>.*<\/grid>/",$page, $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

I get a null array.

Comment: Don't use Regexes to parse HTML. See [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regex, use something like [QueryPath](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://querypath.org/&ei=4grFTb6DMMnx0gH53pGkCA&usg=AFQjCNF5rtGrlfb6lb_lpJ-ol882xNaiYw&sig2=gRSt_CkCSURQHCs6_-rIWw) - I've used it dozens of times with great success. It works like jQuery, for PHP.